# How to get span tag text with selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

With the html code below, I want to get the value of the third span tag inside the div tag. For example when I clicked on the id psr2, I want to retrieve the value 'aaaa, bbbb'.

I have written this code :

```
    n = randint(0,9)
    userPos = 'psr'+str(n)
    WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, str(userPos)))).click()
    userName = WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "countLabel")[n])).text
    print(userName)
```

The html code :

```
<div id="psr2" uid="19202" class="treeNode">
  <nobr>
    <a class="focusableNode" href="#r2" onclick="return false;" tabindex="0" onkeydown="ps.onKeyDown(this);">
      <span role="presentation">
        <span id="countLabel" class="hidden-label">Elément de liste 3 sur {5}</span>
        <span>aaaa, bbbb</span>
        <label name="SelectInfo" class="hidden-label"></label>
      </span>
    </a>
  </nobr>
</div>


<div id="psr3" uid="6653" class="treeNode">
  <nobr>
    <a class="focusableNode" href="#r3" onclick="return false;" tabindex="0" onkeydown="ps.onKeyDown(this);">
      <span role="presentation">
        <span id="countLabel" class="hidden-label">Elément de liste 4 sur {5}</span>
        <span>xxxx, yyyy</span>
        <label name="SelectInfo" class="hidden-label"></label>
      </span>
    </a>
  </nobr>
</div>
```

Could you, please, help me to find the userName ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `following-sibling` `xpath`

```
n = randint(0,9)
userPos = 'psr'+str(n)
WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, str(userPos)))).click()
userName = WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XAPTH, "//span[@id='countLabel']/following-sibling::span"))).text
print(userName)
```

or `following`

```
n = randint(0,9)
userPos = 'psr'+str(n)
WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, str(userPos)))).click()
userName = WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XAPTH, "//span[@id='countLabel']/following::span[1]"))).text
print(userName)
```

---

Update.

```
n = randint(0,9)
userPos = 'psr'+str(n)
WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, str(userPos)))).click()
xpath="//div[@id='{}']//span[@id='countLabel']/following-sibling::span".format(userPos)
userName = WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XAPTH,xpath))).text
print(userName)
userName = WebDriverWait(browser, maxTimeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XAPTH,xpath))).get_attribute(textContent)
print(userName)
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions but it doesn't work. Is it because the id 'countLabel' is present in every div?

Comment: Is it throwing any error?

Comment: @ChristopheC. : can you try the updated one, let me know the status?

Comment: it works with the version containing .text but not with the version .get_attribute(textContent). the error is "NameError: name 'textContent' is not defined". Many thanks for helping me find a solution so quickly. It's true that I never think of "following-sibling"

Comment: @ChristopheC. : Happy the it works for you finally.